# How to allow VPN traffic in Firewall Outbound rules?

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall

I'm blocking Outbound connections by default (except those specified by Allow rules) in Windows 10 firewall.

there is only one problem I'm facing, I can't connect to VPN (PPTP or L2TP). this is built-in VPN (connection made in Windows 10 settings). how can I solve this?

when I add all services to the allow list, it works and I can connect to the VPN, but other than that I can't.

[image]

I obviously don't want to add all services to the allow list in Outbound connections I need to know which service(s) I should exactly allow for it to work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem, just had to enable these rules that are, **by default, disabled** in Windows firewall Outbound rules.

[image]